# React - Child Components as Behaviors?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to inject capabilities into a parent component via child decorators.  For example,

```
<OpenLayers>
    <GeoJsonLayer url="https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson"/>
</OpenLayers>
```

I'm having to use a context to do it, but I'm interpreting that as a warning sign, since there are many places that say, 'if you're using context you're probably doing something wrong'.  It seems like `child.props.parent` should already exist but, again, the fact that I'm looking for that must be another warning sign.

Perhaps it's the parent's responsibility to iterate through it's children and invoke methods on them that modify themselves?  But where would that be done? 
 How to get access to the component instance?

How can a child modify its parent without the parent having explicit knowledge of the child?  I'm looking for existing pattern that allows child components to modify the behavior of the parent component that don't invoke using "context".

Here are the two approaches I've tried so far.  The first seems to be better design but the second allows me to extend the  capabilities via introducing child components (e.g. ):

```
    // one alternative is to not use child components but properties...
    this.props.geoJsonUrl && GeoJsonLayer.addGeoJsonLayer(map, this.props.geoJsonUrl);

    // another is to use child components and pass parent to a handler..
    Children.forEach(this.props.children, c => {
        c;
        if (typeof c === "string") return;
        if (typeof c === "number") return;
        let child: any = c;
        if (child.type === GeoJsonLayer) {
            GeoJsonLayer.addGeoJsonLayer(map, c.props.url);
        }
    });

    // I would prefer that the child trigger a cascading event that the parent could receive
    // and process
```

Using props only:

```
        <OpenLayers
            orientation={orientation}
            controls={{ mousePosition: true }}
            bingImagerySet="AerialWithLabels"
            labels={true}
            setCenter={setCenter}
            center={this.state.center}
            zoom={this.state.zoom}
            geoJsonUrl="http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson"/>
```

Using child:

```
        <OpenLayers
            orientation={orientation}
            controls={{ zoom: true, zoomToExtent: true }}
            setCenter={setCenter}
            center={this.state.center}
            zoom={this.state.zoom}
            osm={false}>
            <GeoJsonLayer url="http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson" />
        </OpenLayers>
```

Comment: Have you tried making a [High Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)?

Comment: Are OpenLayers and GeoJsonLayer your components or, 3rd party?

Comment: Mine...I have full control over the source.  I was groping with HOC but haven't seen it as the solution.  I'll give it a closer look.

Comment: How many layers you're probably going to work with? One?

Comment: Probably would have bing, osm, ags basemaps of various flavors as well as drawing layers, geojson layers, kml layers, etc.  It would depend but more than one is possible, yes.

Comment: I found a working example from an actual library that depends on context.  Is this a valid pattern to follow or was the author missing something?  It seems reasonable to me, but again, the "context" warnings make me fear otherwise:
https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers/blob/master/src/controls/mouse-position.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

You would have some kind of a LayerController that has a list of layers in its state, and an addLayer that should be invoked on each Layer's mount, then, you pass the list of layers to the intermediate OpenLayers component through props.

Comment: How would I detect when each layer mounts without specifying a `onmount` property in every single layer?  Seems lifting state requires lowering state into consumer properties via explicit mention (or via "context").  So perhaps context is appropriate in this scenario?  If not, how to prevent implementation clutter in the markup?

Comment: About using context: despite the [context warnings](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), it's currently a valid implementation. [Redux's Provider](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/Provider.js), for example, uses React's Context in it's implementation, so you shouldn't be so afraid of using it, when you have such situation.

Comment: Very good.  Will accept this answer as it seems like the best way of solving it when context is not an option.  And it mentions that context *is* an option, and not being abused in this scenario.

Comment: About onMount handler: yes, you would need to pass the Controller's onMount to all children Layers, so they can be call it in their componentDidMount. To avoid repetitive implementation, you could implement a Higher Order Component that does that for you.

Comment: BTW, if you're using Redux (or some other state management library), for example, you could dispatch an action for each child Layer's componentDidMount as well, then you would get rid of your context by using Redux's Provider's context, and connect OpenLayers with the corresponding store state.

Comment: I'm too new to react to attempt Redux, but it sounds similar to what I was initially hoping for: the child component to trigger an event that bubbles up through the react-dom until a parent handles it.  Redux must skip the 'bubbling' and inform a provider instead, which updates state and cascades back down?  After seeing the complexity with child components I think nested properties and a heavily configurable <OpenLayers> component fits with the reacts way of agnostic children.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a prop `onMount` to the child component that takes a function. Then, in the child's `componentDidMount()` you could call this function. This basic principal stands for any communication from child to parent. You implement a property that receives a handler for some event, then call that handler when the event occurs.

**Edit**: After looking again, I think I understand the desired use case better.

You want to allow users of the `OpenLayers` component the ability to pick and choose layers in a compositional way, and not have to worry about the wiring up of the actual layers in the parent.

You could transparently pass an interface-like object to the children that is implemented by the parent. This property would get added when rendering the child component.

```
class OpenLayers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { };
    this.layerApi = {
      setupGeoJsonLayer: ({ url }) => // do something with state etc.
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { layerApi } = this;
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div> 
        { 
          !children ? null : React.Children(children, child => 
            React.cloneElement(child, { layerApi }))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class GeoJsonLayer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.layerApi.setupGeoJsonLayer(this.props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(next) {
    if (next.props.url !== this.props.url)
      this.props.layerApi.setupGeoJsonLayer(next.props);
  }

  render() {
    // what is rendered here?
  }
}
```

Now each layer would have the means of manipulating the parent according to the parent's API passed down in the props.

You would have to make sure the parent `OpenLayers` triggers its render cycle accordingly. Also, each layer would most likely have an empty `render()` method because they rely on the parent to render content and are only there to modify the render output of the parent. For these reasons, I think the props only approach might be better.

Comment: Problem with this is that the parent needs to know about the child, right?  In this case the <OpenLayers> component would need to render() the <GeoJsonLayer> wouldn't it?  I assume you're saying the "onMount" is implemented on the parent/OpenLayers but I'd have no access to that in the calling context (I just added a usage example to question).

Comment: Oh!  I think I see where you're going with this.  The "onMount" would be implemented at a controller level...above both the <OpenLayers> and <GeoJsonLayer> and would need to know the details of both?  It would need to get the "map" from <OpenLayers> state and get the "url" property from <GeoJsonLayer>.  If I'm understanding you correctly, are there examples that already do this that I could study?

Comment: edited the answer to show a different approach of handling this.

Comment: You're exactly right on the desired use case but it seems React.cloneElement is just a "context" workaround.  I'm wanting react to treat child components as nested properties but maybe what I need are nested properties.  They seem to work perfectly fine:

`<OpenLayers controls={{ draw: { point: this.state.drawPointTest, polygon: true } }}/>`

Albeit less convenient to the user, does this seem like the proper approach?  Maybe a "higher order component" could inject a child components properties into the parent components state but nested properties makes state ownership expicit.